# How can I construct my sqlite query to return rows that contain data in any order?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I would like to be able to return rows of data that contains the user's input, but in any particular order. Here is my example:

One particular column can contain any one of multiple of the following letters:
A B C D E F

Such that:

```
letters_column
A
BC
A
FB
AC
...
```

What I would like to do is if the user types in "BF", I would like to return the row that has the data 'FB'.

I know I can make a query like this:

```
select * from table where letters_column like '%BF%' and where letters_column like '%FB%';
```

However, I would like to avoid making logic to create such a query as it would get hairy pretty quickly, since the user can enter more letters.

Comment: Could you share what your particular use case is?  If a user types 10 distinct characters, do you really want to search for all 3.6 million permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query to *reject* the individual letters you *don't* want. Something like this for the example:

`select * from table where  not letters_column like '%A%' and not letters_column like '%C%' and not letters_column like '%D%' and not letters_column like '%E%'`

Comment: This did it! I'm still a little inexperienced with sql in general and wasn't aware of the NOT clause. Nice work!